# Where is FOSUserBundle official documentation?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I could not find the official documentation for FOSUserBundle. How can I access it?

Comment: Voted to reopen. Asking for *official documentation* is on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need is provided in official documentation at  https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/192c53916942847aee687722af54f431aead0b70/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: Is your answer still valid if all links would be broken? Not? Then you want to put the essential parts of the link into your answer!

Comment: @Rizier123 The question is asking for the location of (i.e. a link to) the official documentation, which this answer has provided.